# Libquic Crash on iOS 15+

Tags: ios

My app is encountering crashes that I'm unable to reproduce during testing. The app crashes consistently when it goes into the background.

```
Thread 7 name:
Thread 7 Crashed:
0   libquic.dylib                   0x00000001c95fa6a4 quic_recovery_pto + 1764 (quic_recovery.c:0)
1   libquic.dylib                   0x00000001c95fa694 quic_recovery_pto + 1748 (quic_recovery.c:761)
2   libquic.dylib                   0x00000001c95f9204 quic_recovery_timer_fired + 644 (quic_recovery.c:848)
3   libquic.dylib                   0x00000001c960695c quic_timer_run + 328 (quic_timer.c:174)
4   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018246794c __nw_protocol_instance_schedule_wakeup_block_invoke + 56 (protocol_implementation.m:4127)
5   libnetwork.dylib                0x000000018218faf0 __nw_context_reset_timer_block_with_time_block_invoke + 220 (context.m:1633)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001812db298 _dispatch_client_callout + 16 (object.m:559)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181280028 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412 (inline_internal.h:2557)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000181290d64 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1304 (source.c:570)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018128567c _dispatch_workloop_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1600 (inline_internal.h:2598)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018128dfac _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 712 (queue.c:6589)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c9bc95bc _pthread_wqthread + 272 (pthread.c:2436)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c9bcc86c start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)
```

Any insights or suggestions would be highly valuable. Has anyone else experienced a similar issue when the app enters the background?

Thanks in advance!

Examined crash reports without finding a consistent pattern.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)